# Dynamically Constructed and Deeply Nested Forms in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I been trying to find a solution for my problem for a couple days without luck. I get JSON data from the backend from which I construct a nested form. The structure of the form is dynamic (depends on what comes from the backend) and its values need to be pre-populated (this is included in the data).

To give you an idea, the format of the data can be something like this:

```
export const data = [
  {
    name: "fieldset 1",
    fields: [
      { type: "text", inputs: null, values: ["hi"] },
      { type: "radio", inputs: ["1", "2", "3"], values: ["1"] }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "fieldset 2",
    fields: [
      { type: "text", inputs: null, values: ["hi"] },
      { type: "radio", inputs: ["1", "2", "3"], values: ["1"] }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `fieldset`s in the array needs to be rendered one after the other.
Each `fieldset` has multiple `input` fields of various types. The input fields also have a value selected (`values` array).

Rendering this with the correct values is easy. **What's difficult is when the user presses a button, the modified values need to be aggregated and sent back to the backend.**

One solution that comes to mind is to provide leaf nodes (the actual input components) a function to update the state at the top level.

However if you think about it / try it out, you'll realize such functions are hard to create and pass to the right components.

How can I solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a potential solution to this problem which involved keeping the state local for each input (leaf node), but then also directly mutating the data when a value changes. To give you an idea of what I mean:

Let's say we create a component `<Form data={data} />` and pass it the required data.

Then somewhere down the tree, there will be a component which is like so, e.g.:

```
function InputField({ field }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(field.values[0]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    // mutate data directly - this doesn't cause a rerender
    // but mutates the data since we are accessing it by reference
    field.values[0] = e.target.value;
    // setState locally to cause rerender
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={value} />;
}
```

However colleagues aren't comfortable with this method, and neither am I.